# How to retrieve and edit the right textview, which you make with code, and not with main.xml?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am making a new textview with this code:

```
    TextView score = new TextView (this);
    score.setTag("scoreteller");
    score.setHeight(25);
    score.setWidth(30);
    layout.addView(score);
```

Now my question is, how am I able to retrieve this textview later on, in a new method?

Not with the findViewById() method, because I don't know it. If I add this sentence:

```
score.setId(9);
```

and then use findViewById(R.id.9) it gives an error: Syntax error on token ".9", delete this token.

So how can I retrieve it to change it's text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `findViewById(R.id.9)` with `findViewById(9)`. You can also use `findViewByTag("scoreteller");`

Answer (score 2):

don't use `findViewById(R.id.9)` just do `findViewById(9)`

I don't know why you need that, if you make your `score` variable a class member, you can access it easily. So just make it a class member and you don't need to call `findViewById(9)` anywhere. It is also faster as it doesn't need to search in the layout for this id...